# media query was working fine but suddenly doesn't work anymore

Tags: html, css, media-queries

It worked before but all of a sudden it stopped working :(

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
form,
button,
input {
     width: 80vw !important;
    }
}


<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

I have html, css and js code included in the link below:

[DEMO: CodePen](http://codepen.io/mrfishball/pen/LNrJdP)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is an invisible special character inserted into your code.

It's making the declaration invalid, which calls CSS error-handling into play, and the rule is ignored.

If you copy and paste the code into Notepad, you'll see it.

[image]

In computer science we call this *a focused, non-repeating phantasm, or class-5 free roaming vapor... real nasty one, too!* :-)

The simple solution is to just delete that media query and re-type it.

Comment: Sublime didn't catch it either. Very strange I don't know how it got in my code. Finally I don't have to waste anymore time on this. Thanks alot!